# How to filter a DataFrame column according to tuple index?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the old dataframe with my desired output below it.

Old DataFrame

```
Column
(name,birthday,13)
(name,birthday,14)
(name,birthday,13)
(name,birthday,25)
(name,birthday,16)
```

New DataFrame

```
Column
13
14
13
25
16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
df['columns New'] = df['Column'].str[2]
```